# How do I put a conditional in the context of a popup?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am working with a map, and i am trying to print some information on a pop up. All the information is being extracted correctly from the object, but I want to put an If statement inside and it doesn't seem to be working.

```
  const opcionesPopup = L.popup()
              .setContent(`<h3> LINEA ${subte.properties.linea} </h3>
                          <h3>Estación: ${subte.properties.estacion} </h3>
                          <p><b>Destino:<b> ${subte.properties.destino_bo} </p>
                          <p><b>Escalera mecánica:</b> ${ if ((subte.properties.escalera_m) == "False") {"It doesn't have stairs"} }</p>
```

The only thing that is not working is the IF statement. How should I use it in this context?

Comment: May just be an issue of the `}` of the if statement terminating the ternary bracket before you actually mean it to terminate.  Since your if statement consists of a single expression for the true case, try removing the `{}` around the desired string result.  Otherwise, extract the logic to a method and you can call the method from inside the template literal

Comment: Also verify that your if conditional is actually evaluating to `true`

Comment: just tried it, but it did not work ):

Comment: the error i have in the console is 'unexpected token 'if'

Comment: Oooooooh, change to use a ternary instead.  `${ subte.properties.escalera_m === "False" ? "It doesn't have stairs" : "" }`

Comment: it worked! thank you very much

Comment: You are also missing a </b> after ${subte.properties.destino_bo}